# Anonymous closure can not be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Can smb explain what is the problem, how should I modify my code?

I need to filter `CKRecord`s returned from `CloudKit`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    let myfunc2 = myfunc(names, { (records: [CKRecord], error: NSError) in
        if error == nil {

            let records2 = records.filter($0.value > sourceIndexPath.row && $0.value < destinationIndexPath.row)

            let mro = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [], recordIDsToDelete: [])

        } else {

        }
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to write closures: with explicit argument names, or by referring to the arguments as $0, $1 etc.

For example, these two things are equivalent:

```
// implicit argument names, $0 and $1
let x = reduce(1...5, 0) { $0 + $1 }

// explicit argument names i and j
let y = reduce(1...5, 0) { i, j in i + j }
```

But you can’t mix these things – either you name the arguments, or you use `$n`.  You can’t do both:

```
// name the arguments, but still use $0 and $1
let x = reduce(1...5, 0) { $0 + $1 }
// compiler error: Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used
// inside a closure that has explicit arguments
```

In your example, it looks like you’ve forgotten to supply a closure to the `filter` method.  This means your `$0` isn’t inside a new closure without arguments – so the Swift compiler thinks your `$0` is referring to the outer closure that names it’s arguments explicitly as `records` and `error`.  So it’s complaining you can’t refer to arguments as `$0` inside a closure with explicit argument names.

(the fix is of course to actually supply a closure to `filter` i.e. replace your `()` with `{}`)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error for a totally different reason.

I was returning a closure instead of an array.

I was doing

```
return { cars.map {...}}
```

Removing the extra curly braces fixed it. All I did to fix it was:

```
return  cars.map {...}
```