# Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit argument

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, closures

I am relatively new to Swift and is still grasping the concept of closures.
I have already read this post([Anonymous closure can not be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433782/anonymous-closure-can-not-be-used-inside-a-closure-that-has-explicit-arguments)).
However,the answer is to change the filter from () to {} but I do not know how to implement that to my function.

```
    <<< ImageRow()
            {
                $0.tag = "Image"
                $0.title = "Choose your profile pic"
                if let tutorPic = currentuser!.objectForKey("ProfPhoto") as! PFFile!
                {
                    tutorPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({(imageData:NSData?,error:NSError?)->Void in
                        if(error == nil)
                        {
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                            print("YOOWAHH")
                            print(image)
                            print("***********")
                            self.imagez = image
                            print(self.imagez)
                            $0.value = imagez


                        }
                    })


                }


        }
```

**The error is at line `$0.value = imagez`**.

I downloaded the image data from Parse and want to set it as my default value for my form.However the compiler says I already have explicit arguments so it does not know how to refer to form's arguments instead.How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that because each block is handled separately for dispatch and such, that it does not know how to properly make a reference back to the other block for `$0`. Regardless of whether you explicitly defined the enclosing block, the compiler is going to assume that that's the block you meant when you say `$0`.

To resolve this, simply say in your top block: `let myButton = $0`, and then refer to `myButton` in the enclosing block.

In the future, if you don't know what the form of the block should be, simply re-write out the function call, and autocomplete will bring the rest of the block format back.